# Get index of words in a sentence

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a parallel text. Each line contains source languase (src) and target language (tgt). In both the src and tgt there are some expressions between brackets. the file looks like this

```
parallel(src('he is a [good man]'),tgt('lui è un [buon uomo]')). 

parallel(src('she is a [good woman]'),tgt('lei è una donna buona')). 

parallel(src('he is a beautiful man]'),tgt('lei è una bella donna')).
```

So in some lines there are expressions between brackets and in other lines there are no expressions between brackets.

I want to extract beside each line the expressions between brackets and the position of the first word of the expression in both the src and tgt language. 
I tried this code

```
with open(file) as fi:
    for line in fi.readlines():
    src = line[12:line.index('tgt')]
    tgt = line[line.index('tgt'): ]
    srcs = src.split()
    tgts = tgt.split()
    ss = ""
    tt = ""
    match = re.search(r"\[(.*?)\]",src)
    if match:
        ss = match.group(1)
    match = re.search(r"\[(.*?)\]",tgt)
    if match:
        tt = match.group(1)

    print line, [[ss, ':', srcs.index('['+ss.split()[0])],[ tt,':', tgts.index('['+tt.split()[0])]]
```

It works well for the lines where there are expressions between brackets, but for those where there are no expressions between brackets, it gives me the error "IndexError: list index out of range"

The expected output is

```
parallel(src('he is a [good man]'),tgt('lui è un [buon uomo]')). [[good man:3][buon uomo:3]

parallel(src('she is a [good woman]'),tgt('lei è una donna buona')).[[good woman:3][]] 

parallel(src('he is a beautiful man]'),tgt('lei è una bella donna')). [[]:[]]
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Include full error message in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because `ss.split` does produce a list of 0 words. The simple fix would be:

```
if not ss or not tt:
    print(line, "[[]:[]]")
else:
    print line, [[ss, ':', srcs.index('['+ss.split()[0])],[ tt,':', tgts.index('['+tt.split()[0])]]
```

A more complex fix would be to do it properly, namely:

```
source = '[]'
match = re.search(r"\[(.*?)\]", src)
if match:
    source_phrase = match.group(1)
    tmp = src[:match.start()]
    source_position = len(tmp.split())
    source = "[{}:{}]".format(source_phrase, source_position)

target = '[]'
match = re.search(r"\[(.*?)\]", tgt)
if match:
    target_phrase = match.group(1)
    tmp = tgt[:match.start()]
    target_position = len(tmp.split())
    target = "[{}:{}]".format(target_phrase, target_position)

print line, "[{}: {}]".format(source, target)
```

Comment: @ Antti Haapala    this is the new output                                                                            parallel(src('he is a [good man]'),tgt('lui è un [buon uomo]')). 
 [['good man', ':', 3], ['buon uomo', ':', 3]]
parallel(src('she is a [good woman]'),tgt('lei è una donna buona')). 
 [[]:[]]
parallel(src('he is a beautiful man]'),tgt('lei è una bella donna')).
 [[]:[]]

Comment: But the expected output is                                                                                          parallel(src('he is a [good man]'),tgt('lui è un [buon uomo]')). [[good man:3][buon uomo:3]

parallel(src('she is a [good woman]'),tgt('lei è una donna buona')).[[good woman:3][]] 

parallel(src('he is a beautiful man]'),tgt('lei è una bella donna')). [[]:[]]

Comment: I copied the upper code exactly from your example. Your problem was `IndexError`, not output formatting.

Comment: @ Antti Haapala  your first code works, but for sentenecs where there are espressions only in src or tgt, it gives empty bracktes, but in this case it would gives the expression